# Storybook built version stories crashing when using rewiremock

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, storybook

When building storybook statically, the stories using `rewiremock` crash.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Create a story
2. Install and import `rewiremock`
3. Create a mock like

```
rewiremock('./helpers/sessionHistory')
  .callThrough()
  .with({
    getLastSession: () => ({
      email: 'mocked-mail',
      name: 'mockedName',
    }),
  })
  .toBeUsed(); // always check was the mock used, or not.
```

4. Build storybook
5. Open the static page.
6. See error
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved here (https://github.com/theKashey/rewiremock/issues/89)

> Hi,
>   I added the HMR plugin and the error persisted, but then I forced development mode to the webpack config (the build was using prod by default) and it worked.